# CatBoostClassifier fail to train on Databricks cluster

Tags: catboost

I am getting a very strange error with CatBoost Spark on Databricks cluster.
Below is the error; The CatBoostClassifier.fit() will fail on starter code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAa95.png)